# JS : Display onclick content inside an html loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for display a preview when user clicks on glyphicon. I tried some things, but up to now, I don't overcome to display the picture.

I have a very simple HTML code with Javascript inside like this :

```
{% for document in publication.documents.all %}
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <script>
                    document.getElementById('cover-icon{{ document.id }}').onclick=function(){
                    // Remove any element-specific value, falling back to stylesheets
                    document.getElementById('coverPDF{{ document.id }}').style.display='';
                    };
                </script>

                <td class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-blackboard cover-icon" id="cover-icon{{ document.id }}"></span>
                    <div id="coverPDF{{ document.id }}" style="display: none;">
                        {% if document.format == 'pdf' %}

                            <script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

                              <script type="text/javascript">
                              var document_upload = "{{ document.upload }}";
                              pdfjsLib.getDocument('http://localhost:8000/media/'+document_upload).then(function (pdf) {
                                pdf.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
                                    var scale = 0.30;
                                    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                                    var canvas = document.getElementById('test{{ document.id }}');
                                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                                    canvas.height = viewport.height;
                                    canvas.width = viewport.width;

                                    var renderContext = {
                                        canvasContext: context,
                                        viewport: viewport
                                    };
                                    page.render(renderContext);
                                });
                              });
                            </script>
                            <canvas id="test{{ document.id }}" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm looping over a list of document objects and for each object, I would like to click on glyphicon in order to display the preview given by the second JS script inside with PDF.js.
This second one works fine, but I don't overcome to display the preview.

Could you help me ?
I'm pretty new with javascript.

The code which needs to be improved is :

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('cover-icon{{ document.id }}').onclick=function(){
    // Remove any element-specific value, falling back to stylesheets
    document.getElementById('coverPDF{{ document.id }}').style.display='';
                    };
</script>
```

Comment: Repeating the script tags in a loop doesn't seem correct ..?

Comment: @Teemu Yes but I have to set the script inside my loop because I'm using django variables. The second script should be inside, but the first one too, because I'm looping over id which contains django variables.

Comment: Most of the scripts seems to manipulate the HTML with the "Django variables", why not create the HTML at the server-side? And definitely you should not need to add possibly tens of pdf.js scripts ...

Comment: Because I don't know How I can do that. And I thought my script was good except this issue according to display part.